# ADO Connection CreateInstance Fails On Windows Server 2003

Tags: c++, ado

I have an application that runs fine on Windows 7 but is failing on Server 2003. The line that fails is the third line below

```
_ConnectionPtr pConnection = NULL;
::CoInitialize(NULL);
HRESULT hr = pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
```

The HRESULT returned is 0x80004002 (Interface not supported). Both machines have the MDAC installed and I can't see why I am getting this error. Any reasons this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help...

[An ADO application does not run on down-level operating systems after you recompile it on a computer that is running Windows 7 SP 1 or Windows Server 2008 R2 SP 1 or that has KB983246 installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589)

Comment: That was indeed the problem and after installing the windows update it now works. Thanks.