# ADO objects instance creation failed on the target computer

Tags: c++, sql, ado

I created an MFC application using VC++ 6.0 on my development computer installing Windows XP SP3. In this application, I used ADO objects to access SQL database server :

```
CoInitialize (NULL);
try 
{
 _ConnectionPtr pConn;
  HRESULT hr = pConn.CreateInstance (__uuidof (Connection));
  if (FAILED (hr))
  {
   AfxMessageBox ("Can't create intance of Connection");
  }
  //...
}
//...
```

Of course, the app works fine on my computer. However, I copied the whole Release folder of the app and then run it on another computer with Windows XP SP3 installed, the app failed at creating the Connection object with `hr = -2147467262`.

I searched on the internet much but don't see any resolution.

Does anyone know this issue and could you give me some guides on that?

Comment: Is ADO installed on the target computer?

Comment: An MDAC install msi appropriate for your target platform would probably serve you well. and your HRESULT is `0x80004002`, `E_NOINTERFACE`

Comment: @NeilKnight: according to Microsoft, the ADO was already installed along with Windows XP SP3, it is MDAC as WhozCraig mentioned. I checked the version of MDAC on both computers and saw they're same: 2.81.1132.0 (looked in the registry). Someone said there may have change of IID of ADO objects on other computers but why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: I have this same issue:
It seems similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363878/ado-connection-createinstance-fails-on-windows-server-2003?answertab=active#tab-top

But that fix did not work for me.

The application is build on VS2012/Windows 7/x64.
The issue appears to be the  __uuidof(Connection) call.  On Win7 it returns a guid {00000514-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4} (converted to string here).

On XP and Windows Vista the GUID returns a 0 (as string).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @gullumullog Did you resolve the issue?