# Application crashes due to issue with MSVCR110.dll on Vista and XP

Tags: qt, visual-c++, runtime-error, msvcrt

I am having trouble diagnosing an issue running my C++ (Qt) application.

I build the application on Visual Studio 2012 on a windows 7 machine, using Qt 4.8.5.
I compile using the switches:  /D_USING_V110_SDK71_ which originally fixed my issues with targetting (as per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx)

When I run the application on Windows 7, it runs fine; but on Vista and XP I get this message in my Event Viewer: Application log:

```
Faulting application xxxBridge.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x515094ff, faulting module MSVCR110.dll, version 11.0.51106.1, time stamp 0x5098858e, exception code 0x40000015, fault offset 0x000a327c, process id 0x11e0, application start time 0x01ce299785ba32c0.
```

I have another similar application built at the same time with many similarities, and it runs fine on Vista and XP.

Can someone possibly help me diagnose the issue?  Or make suggestions how I can diagnose the issue, or suggestions of tools to help?

Comment: Run the process under the debugger and see what happens.

Comment: the problem is the application works fine on Windows 7, so running under the debugger occurs in VS 2012 on Windows 7, so the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Visual Studio has [a splendid remote debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y7f5zaaa.aspx).

Comment: Did you define _WIN32_WINNT (or whatever it is) correctly for XP?

Comment: You can't remote debug XP applications with 2012: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx
    "Remote Debugging
The Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012 do not support remote debugging on an XP client. When debugging on Windows XP is required, it is recommended to use the debuggers of an older version of Visual Studio, such as Visual Studio 2010, for local or remote debugging. This is in line with the Windows Vista experience for Visual Studio 2012 RTM, which is a runtime target but not a remote debugging target."

Answer (score 0):

I manually debugged using cout.

I tracked it down to an issue with ADO, same as this user is experiencing:
[ADO objects instance creation failed on the target computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363308/ado-objects-instance-creation-failed-on-the-target-computer)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2):

you need the redistributable attached to your version of studio. drop the DLL into the same folder as your application.